# Why are 32-bit registers divided into 4 parts?

Tags: cpu-registers

I'm learning about registers. It looks like 32-bit registers are divided up so that they can be accessed as 8-bit registers. This looks very inefficient. Performance would be improved if they didn't do this. So why do they do it?

Also, it costs extra money to design them like this. Why not make the CPU cheaper by not doing it?

Comment: You seem to think they can't be accessed simultaneously -- they can.

Comment: Even if they can, what for? It makes the CPU more expensive.

Comment: What about accessing just 16 bits? How would a 32-bit register be MORE efficient for that? Or accessing 8 bits? There are many times when all is needed is 8 bits. Then you need something in the middle to essentially "dump" those extra bits. THAT's expensive.

Comment: Then why not change it so that people don't need to access 8 or 16 bits. Just have them access 32 bits.

Comment: As I said, that's expensive (in the wasteful sense)

Answer (score 2):

Because if you're only dealing with 8bit values, it'd be inefficient to have issue all the bitmasks to limit those 32/64bit register to just the 8bits you're working on.

So, x86 registers have

```
AH/AL = high/low 8bits of a 16bit register
AX = whole 16bit register
EAX = whole 32bit register
```

It's far more efficient, in terms of instruction size to have

```
mov ah, 0xXX   (2 bytes)
```

rather than forcing

```
mov ax, 0x00XX  (3 bytes)
mov eax, 0x000000XX  (7 bytes)
```

As for "designing the cpu to make it cheaper" - it's for backwards compatibility. All modern x86 processors are actually internally a RISC design, with a major chunk of silicon dedicated to taking the x86 instructions coming in and converting them into the CPU's own internal micro-ops (which is basically a RISC instruction set).

Comment: What if they didn't need backwards compatibility. Would there still be any good reason to do it?

Comment: Sure, not everyone has to work with only 32bit or 64bit values. And it's not like ah/al are completely seperate transistors from ax or eax. They're just shortcuts to access only certain portions of one single large register.

Comment: If backward compatibility was not taken into considerations, almost all previous programs would be un-usable. Such a small change would make an architecture become completely new, and maybe x86 won't be as success as nowadays.

Comment: @nodeninja 64bits + 32bits/16bit compatiblity of amd64/X86_64 won the case when competing to first 64bits only systems (aka IA-64 with itanium : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) because all had to rewritten or at least adapted. When you disrupt technology too much, user field resists more...

Answer (score 2):

The Intel 8080, which was the first "mainstream" microprocessor, had seven main 8-bit registers (A, B, C, D, E, H, and L).  Because memory addresses were 16 bits, instructions that needed to use a non-constant memory operand would use a pair of registers (most commonly H and L, but sometimes B and C, or D and E) to form the address.  Because the registers in the aforementioned pairs were often used together to represent 16-bit values, there were a few instructions which could operate upon the register pairs as 16-bit quantities.  An instruction to add BC to HL would perform the addition by adding C to L, and then by adding B to H (plus a carry if needed).  I'm not familiar enough with the 4004 or 8008 (the two predecessors of the 8080) to know if either of them did anything similar in its architecture.

When Intel produced the 8088, they included a full 16-bit arithmetic unit, but they wanted code which was written for the 8080 to be easily convertible to their new architecture.  On the 8080, a lot of code had been written to "manually" form addresses out of the 8-bit parts, since doing so was often much faster than using the 16-bit instructions to do the math.  For example, if one needed to access some specified table of 256 entries with an index stored in A, one could have done something like (Zilog notation show, but the 8080 had the same instructions):

```
ld   hl,(baseOfTable) ; 16-bit address
ld   c,a
ld   b,#0
add  hl,bc
ld   a,(hl)
```

but if one could make certain the table was aligned on a 256-byte boundary, one could simplify the code considerably:

```
ld   l,a
ld   a,(tableBaseMSB) ; Just load the MSB--assume the LSB is zero
ld   h,a
ld   a,(hl)
```

With the 8088 instruction set, it wouldn't terribly often be useful for code written "from scratch" to access the upper and lower parts of registers separately, but there was a lot of code written for the 8080 which used such techniques, and Intel wanted to make it easy for people to convert such code for use on the 8088.  Allowing registers to be built from 8-bit pieces was helpful in that regard.

Incidentally, there was another advantage to Intel's architecture: since it included four 16-bit only registers and four registers which could be used as either one 16-bit or two 8-bit parts, that made it possible for code to hold 12 values in registers if eight of them were 255 or less, or eleven values if six of them were 256 or less, etc.  When using architectures with more registers, eking out an extra register here and there isn't quite so important, but on the 8088 it was often very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to address portions of the registers has no effect on their performance when used as 32-bit registers. In that case, this capability just isn't used.

CPUs, regardless of their native bit size, need to manipulate 8-bit values very, very often. Strings of text, for example, are frequently manipulated as consecutive 8-bit values. International character sets are often manipulated as sets of consecutive 16-bit values. So being able to operate rapidly on 8-bit and 16-bit values is of tremendous importance.

If you're asking as a practical matter for x86 CPUs, it's too late. The very first PC CPUs didn't even have 32-bit registers, and compatibility has been retained all the way through.

Comment: What if they didn't need to maintain compatibility? Wouldn't it be better to not do it?

Comment: No, because the cost is as close to zero as makes no difference and the benefits are enormous because have to manipulate strings of characters frequently.

Comment: All that extra wiring doesn't make things more complex, expensive, and slow? Why not make characters 32 bits instead?

Comment: No, all that extra wiring doesn't make things more complex, expensive, and slow. Gates and wiring are cheap and nearly free. That's why we can make a CPU for $150 that has a billion of them on it. And making characters 32-bits would be a performance disaster because they would need four times as much space in memory, in cache, and on the bus when being transferred.

Comment: But what about other CPUs, like for embedded systems? Do they do this too? Do they need to process characters?

Comment: You can always fake it with bit operations. Many RISC CPUs do not have any way to address parts of their registers and requires you to fake it with bit operations. But you'd be surprised how many cases there are where you need to operate on small data objects. Pretty much every wire format (including IP and TCP) requires this. Almost every file and transfer format requires this (HTTP, XML, BER, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Backwards compatibility. Processor manufacturers did not wanted to break compatibility with old software. This is the main reason why x86_64 processors still support 16bit software(virtual mode). If you look closely you'll see that majority of the features in x86 architecture are shaped by compatibility concerns. I'm no hating.